# How to find a cell in column B and update status in Column Z?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code to find a cell in column B and update status in Column Z.

```vb
Sub FindAndWrite()
    Dim FindValues() As String
    Dim WriteValue As String
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim TS As Object
    Dim ConcatenateRange As Range
    Dim ExternalWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim ExternalData As Variant
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\2093960\Desktop\tobewritten.xlsx", 1) 'replace "C:\path\to\file.txt" with the path to your file
    
    FindValues = Split(TS.ReadAll, vbCrLf) 'read the values from the file and store them in an array
    TS.Close
    
    WriteValue = "Completed" 'replace "value_to_write" with the value you want to write to column Z
    
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row of column B
    
    Set ExternalWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\2093960\Desktop\tobewritten.xlsx") 'replace with the path to your external file
    ExternalData = Replace(Replace(ExternalWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, "-", "_"), " ", "") 'modify this line to access the cell with your data and replace hyphens with underscores and remove spaces
    
    For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop through each row in column B
        Set ConcatenateRange = Range("A" & i & ":C" & i) 'change this to the range of cells containing your data
        Set FoundCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i)
        For j = 0 To UBound(FindValues) 'loop through each value in the array
            If InStr(Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(ConcatenateRange.Value), ""), "-", "_"), Replace(FindValues(j), "-", "_")) > 0 Or InStr(Replace(ExternalData, "-", "_"), Replace(FindValues(j), "-", "_")) > 0 Then 'check if the current value from the array is in the concatenated range or external data
                FoundCell.Offset(0, 25).Value = WriteValue 'write the WriteValue to column Z in the same row
                Exit For 'exit the inner loop when a match is found
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ExternalWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close the external workbook without saving changes
End Sub
```

The data to find, I get from another Excel workbook, has hyphens and underscores.

I get

> invalid procedure or arguments error in
>
> ```
> If InStr(Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(ConcatenateRange.Value), ""), "-", "_"), Replace(FindValues(j), "-", "_")) > 0 Or InStr(Replace(ExternalData, "-", "_"), Replace(FindValues(j), "-", "_")) > 0 Then 'check if the current value from the array is in the concatenated range or external data
> ```

I tried multiple ways, including changing data type.

Comment: `Replace` and `InStr` are VBA functions and cannot work on Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Instr takes 3 parameters, the first is the starting position to search...

```
If InStr(1, Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(ConcatenateRange.Value), ""), "-", "_"), Replace(FindValues(j), "-", "_"))
```